# What does the 400 error "Access token cannot be refreshed. Please re-authenticate" mean for OneLogin?

Tags: api, onelogin

In the API documentation, OneLogin states that one of the possible error messages could be a 400 with "Access token cannot be refreshed. Please re-authenticate".

https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/oauth20-tokens/refresh-tokens

The docs state that I can call this API if my access token has expired. However, when I make this call after my access token has expired, I get the error message stated above. There is no explanation on the docs on what this means.

The refresh token api *does work* if the access token has not expired.

Any help or explanation on this error message would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means your refresh token has expired. I think there was an issue where refresh tokens were expiring too soon, but I believe it's been addressed.